# Using iText to do text replacement in PDF, first sentence in each paragraph is getting broken up

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation, itext7

I'm using version 7.1.3 of the iText library for Java. I'm doing text replacement on a PDF file template, to create a new PDF file, and the first sentence within each paragraph in the new file is getting broken up.

In other words, a line break seems to be getting added somehow to the middle of the first sentence in each paragraph. Also, some text that was centered within the original PDF doesn't get centered within the new PDF.

Any ideas as to how to resolve this?

Comment: We'll need to see some code to be able to help you.

Comment: Fair enough. Just created a GitHub gist here:

https://gist.github.com/aroc725/25fce0abfd6cd131f8e1ba4f1e1ab329

Comment: According to your code you do this text replacement in pdf form fields. Have you checked the dimensions of your text body field in your template?  It probably is smaller than you expected, so that that first line after text replacement has become too long to fit. Other than that we'd also need your pdf template to understand what's going on.

Comment: Yep, the text field probably needs to be re-sized. But is there a way to deal with this programmatically?

I can call the 'getValueAsString' method on the 'PdfFormField' object representing the text field, and then call the 'length' method to get the number of characters in the text field's string value.

But after casting the 'PdfFormField' object to a 'PdfTextFormField' object and calling the 'getMaxLen' method returns 0.

Comment: How can I get the dimensions of the text body field?

Comment: please could you attach the source pdf you're trying to modify? 
also I'm interested in the result pdf you get as well. Could you take a screeenshot so that one can see the difference?